# Resolve promise two different ways

Tags: javascript, sql, reactjs, promise

I'm currently working on a route based on a promise, this is my promise so far :

```
const allowEdit = (postid, username) => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    db.query(`SELECT * FROM post WHERE id = ${postid} AND username = '${username}'`, (err, results) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log("authorized ===", err);
        resolve(err);
      }
      resolve(results);
    });
  });
};
```

It currently just checks if the user created the post. I then allow that person to edit the post when the promise is fulfilled. However, I want to add another way to resolve to the promise. What I want to do with the promise is to say that either the user created the post (what I currently have) or the user is an admin (I just need to check in my SQL base for this) where only one needs to be fulfilled for the promise to be resolved. How can I incorporate this in to my current code please? All help is much appreciated!

Comment: `promise(resolve , reject)`

Answer (score 0):

Don't issue two SQL statements, instead adapt the one you have so it can detect the two conditions in one go. Something like:

```sql
SELECT 1 
FROM   post 
WHERE  id = ${postid} 
AND    (username = '${username}' OR username IN (SELECT username FROM admins))
```

The way you check for whether the user is an administrator may be different of course. It could maybe be something like:

```sql
SELECT 1 
FROM   post 
WHERE  id = ${postid} 
AND    (username = '${username}' OR username IN (
            SELECT username 
            FROM   users
            WHERE  is_admin = 1)
        )
```

But the common idea is that you perform the check in the same `SELECT` statement.

Finally, the way you check for the user name is vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Make sure to use [parameterised, prepared SQL statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement).